# How to remove blue channel from an image with ImageMagick in bash/console?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

How to remove blue channel from an image with ImageMagick in bash or in console in Linux? I can't understand ImageMagick's syntax.

Comment: I thought it was more of a programming because I expected a bit complicated bash script rather than a mere commend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing a specified channel is covered under the "*Zeroing Color Channels*" section of the [Color Basics documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#zeroing).

```sh
# Evaluate
convert source.jpg -channel Blue -evaluate set 0 +channel out.jpg
```

or...

```sh
# FX zeroing
convert source.jpg -channel Blue -fx 0 +channel out.jpg
```

or...

```sh
# Separate & combine other channels
convert source.jpg -channel Red,Green -separate \
        -background black -combine +channel out.jpg
```